# Which are parse.com ip addresses to restrict calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform

I have a system deployed in AWS which receives calls from parse.com only, and I want to restrict all calls to that server to parse IP addresses in a security group.

Does anybody know which are parse.com IP addresses?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Parse API server IP is 52.1.248.228 but I am not sure if all requests from them will originate from this IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research I found that Parse is running in AWS and their IPs are volatile, they can change like any other EC2 instance, so so far this is not possible.

Thanks